# vba same filter for all pivot charts

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code. I would like to use the code to set the same filters for all pivot charts in the workbook. Specifically, to set the same year in all pivot charts in the whole workbook. Can you help me, please. Thank you

```
Sub Makro2()

Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pch As ChartObject
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pch In sht.ChartObjects

        Set pf = pvt.PivotFields("[Ucetni obdobi].[Rok].[Rok]")

                    pf.VisibleItemsList = Array("[Ucetni obdobi].[Rok].&[2017]")


    Next pch
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: I would create slicers for every pivot table (as many as different sources they have) and then loop through all the slicers and select the same year. If all your pivot charts have the same source, a single slicer will do the trick and no code is needed.

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately this is not possible :-( I have exactly defined the style of the chart and the slicer my boss does not wish :-(

Comment: So what? Put all the slicers inside a hidden worksheet so your boss won't see it...

Comment: thank you for your help, but I can't really do that. I need help fixing my code

Comment: I tried to edit the code, but it still doesn't work. please give me some advice where I have a mistake
Thank you

    Sub Makro2()

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim pch As ChartObject

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each pch In ChartObjects
        For Each pvt In sht.PivotTables

            Set pf = pvt.PivotFields("[Ucetni obdobi].[Rok].[Rok]")

                    pf.VisibleItemsList = Array("[Ucetni obdobi].[Rok].&[2017]")
            Next pvt
          Next pch
    Next sht
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pivot As PivotTable

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pivot In ws.PivotTables

        With pivot.PivotFields("DataColumn1")
            .PivotItems("5000").Visible = False
        End With

    Next pivot
Next sht
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you but on pivot chart it doesn't work for me. I would need to modify the code so that when I write the year 2017, only the year 2017 is filtered in all pivot charts, etc.

Comment: you can do this with charts as well.

    Dim pvtitem As PivotItem
    
    For Each pvtitem In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot2").PivotTables("PivotTableExistingSheet").PivotFields("LOA").PivotItems
        pvtitem.Visible = True
        Select Case pvtitem.Value
            Case "First", "Second"
            Case Else
            pvtitem.Visible = False
        End Select
    Next pvtitem
change this code a bit and you will have the expected results.

Comment: unfortunately it hurts. if I specify it to be for every chart on every sheet, I can't do it :-(

Comment: I forgot to say that my graphs are linked to OLAP databases, so the links " [Ucetni obdobi].[Rok].[Rok]".